# How to set main.js file to add Bootstrap-vue to the Vuex project?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I started a project with vue/vuex and trying to add Bootstrap-vue to it.

How to organize main.js file merging two fragments -

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')

---------------add this:

import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

vuex starting code with bootstrap starting code ?

Answer (score 0):

The upper part is Vue 3, the lower part is Vue 2 - the two do not mix, you have to use the one matching your Vue version.

Note that BootstrapVue does [not yet support Vue 3](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3), so you either have to downgrade to Vue 2, use the compat module, wait a while or switch to a different design system, like Vuetify, PrimeVue, Antd, etc.